# What is the outcome of this function fun?

Tags: linked-list

Integer fun(Node *p) //Linked list

```
  while(p not equals NULL)

      print p-> data

      p=p->next
  End loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a common linked list function. Here is a common linked list architecture:
[image: Linked list]

The idea is that you have blocks with two contents: the actual data and the pointer to the next object of the list.

In the posted code, p is the pointer to the first element of the list.
The intention is to print all the list. So, it follows the steps:

1. Print the first element's data.
2. Update p to point to the next element.
3. Print this element's data.
   and so on until there are no more elements.